# JSON body in string form

Tags: json, karate

I am trying to send json body in HTTP request for POST method, but the problem is some of the strings are actually JSON in string form, so there's some tricky quoting needed to get it right.

Here is the CURL command that works perfectly fine:
curl -X POST https://www.example.com:8080/api/v1/runs -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F tags='{"revision":"master"}'  -F params='{"a":"b"}' -F type=testflow -F wurl=https://github.com/abc/repo

Karate POST request:
Given path '/api/v1/runs'
And request `"{ tags: '{"revision":"master"}', wurl: 'https://github.com/abc/repo', params: '{"a":"b"}', type: 'testflow' }"`

But throws an error:
features.wapi.post_wrun: wapi.post_wrun.feature:14 - evaluation (js) `failed: "{ tags: '{"revision":"master"}', wurl: 'https://github.com/abc/repo', params: '{"a":"b"}', type: 'testflow' }", <eval>:1:12 Expected ; but found revision "{ tags: '{"revision":"master"}', wurl: 'https://github.com/abc/repo', params: '{"a":"b"}', type: 'testflow' }"`
^ in  at line number 1 at column number 12

I have tried the following:

1. I have put the content in Json file for example:
   `{ "url": "https://github.com/abc/repo", "type": "testflow", "tags": { "revision": "master" }, "params": { "a": "b" } }`

`def readJsonbody = read ("../test/feature/test.json").`

2. `def readJSOnbody = karate.readJsonbody("classpath:test.json")`

But seems like no luck, Please let me know if there is any tricky quoting needed to overcome this issue, which works fine in CURL but not in POST request using Karate?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#text

```
* text body =
  """
  { tags: '{"revision":"master"}', wurl: 'https://github.com/abc/repo', params: '{"a":"b"}', type: 'testflow' }
  """
* request body
```

Also note that `karate.readAsString()` would have worked as well: https://github.com/intuit/karate#read-file-as-string

That said I think `-F` in cURL means form-fields, so you may need to do something completely different: https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field

```
* form field tags = '{"revision":"master"}' 
* form field params = '{"a":"b"}'
```

And so on and then a `post`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Multipart form Fields worked ! I appreciate the help! @ptrthomas