# Karate: How to send raw request and disable embedded expressions

Tags: karate, raw

How can I send a raw request wrapped in parentheses and prevent Karate from parsing it as ["embedded expression"](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions)?

Example 1: Correctly sends the string `'(1+2)'` as payload (as expected).

```js
Given request '(1+2)'
```

Example 2: The same string as multi-line is detected as "embedded expression" and converted by Karate to type number `3` (you can see it clearly in the logs and in the receiving API):

```js
Given request
"""
(1+2)
"""
```

**Why is that and how can I send real raw strings, no matter what's inside? In other words: How to disable embedded expressions?**

My background is that I need to send multi-line raw strings as payload. Some sub-strings are wrapped in parentheses and this would then lead to errors in the receiving API (to simplify my question I reduced the examples to 1 line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#text

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* path 'anything'
* text body =
"""
(1+2)
"""
* request body
* method post
```

Refer to the docs for "type conversion" also. And another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64328206/143475